# How to dynamically update an alias in the .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, shell

I am defining an alias in a departmental `.bashrc` file, which is sourced before the individual user `.bashrc` file.  In the individual user `.bashrc` file I would like to be able to add options to the existing alias.  So for example in the first (departmental) `.bashrc` file I have the following:

```
alias my_command = '/usr/local/bin/my_command -option1 -option2'
```

In the user `.bashrc` file I'd like to build on the existing alias, e.g.

```
alias my_command = 'my_command -option3'
```

As written, the alias instruction in the user `.bashrc` file would simply replace the alias of the same name defined in the departmental .bashrc file.  I tried to get around this with the following approach:

```
existing_alias_components=($(type my_command))
```

which returns the words my_command, is, aliased, and to in the first four elements of the array.  I want to capture the remaining array elements, join them back into a string -- say `$string` -- and then issue the command

```
alias my_command="$string -option 3"
```

I'm running into challenges with the fact that the quote characters that surround the first definition of the alias are getting into the first and last array values after the first four.  I can substring them out, but it's getting to be a lot of work for what would be a one-liner in perl.  Is there a more expedient way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a function for this?

Comment: Why would you want to pre-resolve the path? The shell caches PATH lookups, so there's not any performance enhancement from doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply extract the alias value from between the single quotes:

```
 oldalias=$(alias my_command|sed "s/^[^']*'//; s/'$//");
```

and then do

```
 alias my_command="$oldalias -option 3"
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks to everyone who replied, all provided very insightful feedback with great explanations.  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a function instead. For instance:

```
my_command_args=( -option1 -option2 )
my_command() {
  command my_command "${my_command_args[@]}" "$@"
}
```

...after which someone can run:

```
# add a 3rd option on the end:
my_command_args+=( -option-3 )
```

...or, to prepend a new argument:

```
# add a 0th option on the beginning
my_command_args=( -option0 "${my_command_args[@]}" )
```

---

The big advantage here is that you can append data to your alias without needing to safely quote it. For instance, the following would be very bad news with an alias:

```
# This is evil
bad_string='$(rm -rf /tmp)'
alias my_command="$oldalias --fail-if-command-contains=$bad_string"
```

...needing instead to be run through something like `printf '%q'`:

```
# ...can make it safer this way, if using an alias
bad_string='$(rm -rf /tmp)'
printf -v bad_string_safe %q "$bad_string"
alias my_command="$oldalias --fail-if-command-contains=$bad_string_safe"
```

...but it would be perfectly safe without that step if using the function formulation:

```
# This is safe
bad_string='$(rm -rf /tmp)'
my_command_args+=( --fail-if-command-contains="$bad_string" )
```